# set a java application to close when a JavaFX browser window is closed?

Tags: java, javafx, window, exit, terminate

How do I set a java application to close when a JavaFX browser window is closed?

I have a console based application, at the end of the main content, the user is is asked if they would like to view a web page. If yes, open the web page.  If not exit app.

As I understand it, a javaFX app closes when the window is Xed out.  My issue is, the part of my app that is not FX and is command/text does not appear to terminate when window closes.  How can I achieve total app termination when FX window closes.

I will include two classes. One prompts the user to view page and in input n, then terminate.  The other class opens the page.

```js
package mrArray;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/*
 * declare class, subclass of Application.
 * declare, instantiate, initialize vBoxOF,
 */
public class OpenSite extends Application 
{
 VBox vBoxOF = new VBox();

 /*
  * declare method.
  * invoke OpenSite.launch(OpenSite.class);,
  * launch a stand-alone application.
  */
 public static void invokeLaunch() 
 {
  OpenSite.launch(OpenSite.class);
 }
 
 /*
  * declare start(Stage primaryStage),
  * main entry point for all JavaFX applications,
  * declare primaryStageOP,
  * the top level JavaFX container.
  * invoke setId("root"),
  * assign identifier.
  * declare, instantiate, initialize webViewBrowserOL,
  * as node that manages a webEngineOL & displays its content.
  * 
  *  managing one Web page 
  */
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
 {
  vBoxOF.setId("root");

  WebView  webViewBrowserOL = new WebView();
  WebEngine webEngineOL = webViewBrowserOL.getEngine();
  String urlSL = "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html";
  webEngineOL.load(urlSL);
    
  vBoxOF.setPadding(new Insets(30, 50, 50, 50));
  vBoxOF.setSpacing(10);
  vBoxOF.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
  vBoxOF.getChildren().addAll(webViewBrowserOL);

  Scene sceneOL = new Scene(vBoxOF);
  primaryStage.setScene(sceneOL);
  primaryStage.show();
  
  //ViewSiteOrExit.exitApp();
 }
}
```

```js
package mrArray;


public class ViewSiteOrExit 
{
 /*
  * declare fields,
  */
 private static int statePrSIF;
 private static String enterYOrNPrSSOF;
 
 /*
  * declare method,
  * initialize field,
  * while, test(field) is passing execute,
  * switch, evaluates cases with value(field),
  * matching, execute statements,
  * 0, first case, prompt, y drop to if, reset value, use app again,
  * n drop to else, increment field, 1, second case,
  * invoke method to close app, reset field value to prevent double field invocation,
  * return flow to caller to prevent use of closing Scanner,
  */
  public static void viewSitePromptPuSVM() 
  {
   statePrSIF = 0;
   while (statePrSIF < 2) 
   {
    switch (statePrSIF) 
    {
     case 0: 
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("[:-)] One more question?");
      System.out.println("Would you like to see what Oracle has to say about me?");
      System.out.println("Enter ' y ' for yes.");
      System.out.println("Enter ' n ' for no.");
      break;
       case 1:
        goodByePuSVM();
        statePrSIF = 0;
        return;
    }
              
    enterYOrNPrSSOF = MrArray.scannerOF.next();
      
    if(enterYOrNPrSSOF.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 
    {
     statePrSIF = 0;
     System.out.println("[:-)] Well bud, it's been fun.");
     System.out.println("Here is that Orcale thing.");
     System.out.println("See ya later!");
     OpenSite.invokeLaunch();
    }
    else if(enterYOrNPrSSOF.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) 
    {
     statePrSIF++;
    } 
   }
  }
  
  /*
   * declare method,
   * invoke methods, display output,
   * close Scanner, terminate,
   */
  public static void goodByePuSVM()
  {
      System.out.println("[:-)] Well bud, it's been fun.");
      System.out.println("See ya later!");
      
      MrArray.scannerOF.close();
      exitApp();
  }
  
  public static void exitApp()
  {
   System.exit(0); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have nothing to save, you can use `System.exit(0)` on `stage.setOnCloseRequest()` request.

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
});
```

***StreamLined Approach***

Since you are calling JavaFX Application from your Java Application and once you close the JavaFX Application Window, the control will return to the Java Application, I would recommend the following approach.

*In JavaFX Application Class*

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        Platform.exit();
    }
});
```

*In Java Class*

```
OpenSite.invokeLaunch();
...        // Complete your task
if(!Platform.isFxApplicationThread())
      exitApp(); // or System.exit(0);
```

Comment: @ReedWilliams19842004 - you are not learning anything by having everyone else do you work for you. Your questions are all extremely low quality and are in every case a duplicate of dozens of other beginner questions that have been already asked countless times. Do some research and ask specific questions that have not be asked and answers over and over again. **You are probably going to end up with a question ban if you keep going like you are going.**

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Lambda Expression:

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(
    (WindowEvent we) -> {
        Platform.exit();
    });
```